# Eclipse - Synchronize Graphical Editor and Graphical View

Tags: eclipse, view, editor, eclipse-gef

Working with Eclipse GEF.  I have a graphical editor that displays objects.  This was built from a Graphical View that displays the same GEF model.  Basically following the book "The Eclipse Graphical Editing Framework (GEF).  It builds a graphical view first, and then around chapter 12 it switches over to a graphical editor.

My question is what is the common practice to synchronize a View to it's Editor?  As stuff is changed in the Editor, how do I replicate this to the View?

I've done some searching on Google but coming up empty.

The other thing, which I think is probably simple, but I'm probably not seeing it is how do I set the View contents to the Editor when the Editor is open and my view is not?  I.e. when I select Window (Menu) > Show View > ... Do I just grab the active page and active part?  Then check to make sure it's an instance of my graphical editor?

Answer (score 0):

The editor and the view are supposed to be synchronized by the model. Changes in the editor are done to the model. The model notifies the controller about the changes. Controller updates the view. The same should happen with a view if you keep the Controllers for the view.